# How to use a custom PostgreSQL type in SeaORM?

Tags: postgresql, rust, sea-orm

I have the following table in postgres

```sql
create table retailers(id: integer, name: citext);
```

`citext` is just case insensitive text in PostgreSQL.
How do I modify the Entity creation in SeaORM to support that?

When I generate entities in SeaORM in rust, I get the following error:

```
error: Missing macro attribute, either `string_value` or `num_value` should be specified or specify repr[X] and have a value for every entry
  --> src/entity/sea_orm_active_enums.rs:10:5
```

How do I create new types in SeaORM in Rust?